# Area within ROPE region does not have homogeneous color fill when using stat_slab

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ran some multilevel models using `brms` and am following the examples [here](http://mjskay.github.io/tidybayes/articles/tidy-brms.html#intervals-with-densities) to plot draws from the posterior for each parameter.

Here's a toy dataset to reproduce the problem

```
library(brms)
library(tidybayes)
library(tidiverse)

n = 10
n_condition = 5
ABC =
  tibble(
    condition = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), n),
    response = rnorm(n * 5, c(0,1,2,1,-1), 0.5),
    treatment = rnorm(n * 5, c(0,1,2,1,-1), 0.5),
    subject = c(rep("X",(n_condition*n)/2),rep("Y",(n_condition*n)/2))
  )
```

And a toy brms model

```
m = brm(
  response ~ treatment + (1|condition) + (1|subject),
  data = ABC_letters,
  cores = 4, chains = 1,
  iter = 500, warmup = 50
)
```

And the code to plot it.

```
ROPE <- rope_range(m_letters)
m_letters %>%
  spread_draws(b_treatment, r_subject[subject,]) %>% 
  mutate(subject_estimate = b_treatment + r_subject) %>% #print()
  ggplot(aes(y = subject, x = subject_estimate, fill = stat(abs(x) < ROPE))) +
  stat_slab()
```

Then (on my MacOS, Catalina, tidybayes 2.1.1, R 3.6.2) I get:
[image]

This actually started happening on my plots after I changed the xlims using `coord_cartesian`. Then all fills started to look like this.
How can I get rid of that striped pattern and get a solid blue fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bayestestR::rope_range()` returns a vector of two values:

```r
ROPE <- rope_range(m_letters)
ROPE
# [1] -0.1249308  0.1249308
```

However the calculation you are using for the fill colour, `stat(abs(x) < ROPE)`, expects `ROPE` to be a single value, and is `TRUE` if `x` is between `-ROPE` and `ROPE` and `FALSE` otherwise.

For the output of `rope_range()`, a vector of two values giving the min and max of the ROPE, you instead want a test like `stat(ROPE[[1]] < x & x < ROPE[[2]])`. If I do that it works:

```r
ROPE <- rope_range(m_letters)
m_letters %>%
  spread_draws(b_treatment, r_subject[subject,]) %>% 
  mutate(subject_estimate = b_treatment + r_subject) %>% #print()
  ggplot(aes(y = subject, x = subject_estimate, fill = stat(ROPE[[1]] < x & x < ROPE[[2]]))) +
  stat_slab()
```

[image: stat_slab with appropriate fill condition for rope_range output]

Answer (score 0):

Your plot looks fine and gives me the following output.  I am running R 4.0.2 and RStudio version 1.2.5 on windows.  However, my output looks like yours if I expand it horizontally.

[image: output]